# How to attach id's to components dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am building a React App for which I need to know which component is clicked.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

gives the target element, but there could be multiple component having same className and content inside id.

So, i was thinking about adding 'ID' to the component.

The way it works is..

- if ID doesn't exist then add ID to the component

Since ID's are usually unique this would help me in determining component. I am not sure how I can do it using React.

Can someone help me please

Comment: Don't use `document.addEventListener` in conjunction with React at all! Just do `onClick` in those elements you care about.

Comment: @AKX I care about all the elements, I am building collaboration tool where anyone can annotate a component and leave comments.

Comment: Then put a listener on all of them, or a listener on a parent element that looks at the `currentTarget` on the click event.

Comment: As to how to identify each element, a common method is data attributes: `data-element-id="1234"` or similar.

Comment: @AKX but two elements can have same data attribute? much like className?

Comment: Yes, they can, but if you want to be able to address each component uniquely, you'd of course need to give them unique (data attribute) IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example of how you can capture clicks on child elements that have a `data` attribute to identify them.

Here all we do is highlight the last clicked element, but you'd probably do something fancier.

```js
const ids = new Array(40).fill(null).map((_, i) => `${i + 1}`);

function App() {
  const [mark, setMark] = React.useState("");
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
      const elid = e.target.dataset.elid;
      if (!elid) return;
      setMark(elid);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div onClickCapture={handleClick} className="App">
      {ids.map((id) => (
        <div
          data-elid={id}
          key={id}
          className="block"
          style={mark === id ? { background: "orange" } : undefined}
        >
          Element {id}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}
.block {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer and this is super helpful, but I don't want manually do this for each component.

Comment: Well, you're a programmer – don't do it manually then? Besides, if you ever want to persist those annotations others make in your collaboration tool, how would you know what they refer to if the elements didn't have persistent IDs?